# Defining a mail manager using HTML

Tags: html, asp.net

There is a letter layout for outlook with an image in base64 format as well as for gmail with a different image format. How do I define a mail manager using HTML? To display the appropriate image format for a specific mail manager.

A solution is needed due to the fact that a similar format does not work in outlook:
`<img src="image link" onerror="this.src = 'image in base64 format'">`
and also with alt, lowsrc.

Are there any other solutions to this issue?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `onerror="this.src = 'image in base64 format'"` in emails because of the JavaScript in it. The vast majority of email clients block scripts since they can hide malicious content. So the problem is not the image format or the mail manager. An image defined as base64 will work just fine as a source in the `img` HTML tag.

Comment: I agree, but img is not enough, since outlook reads the image in base64 format, but does not work with links via cdn. I need to output to outlook in base64 format, and to Gmail in url format via cdn, because Gmail does not read base64.
To do this, I need to recognize the mail service.